# why I have reshape error when I np.array (Image)

Tags: python, machine-learning, python-imaging-library

so I'm working on a handwriting identification project and it works fine using the IamDB. However, when I try to take a picture of handwriting myself, I got this error, any idea how to fix it? I tried changing the picture into grayscale and it doesn't work

```
images = []
PTH = Path_to_test 
#filename  = os.path.basename(PTH[0])
filename = PTH[0]
#******************************************************
print (filename)
im = Image.open(filename)
#print ("cu")
cur_width = im.size[0]
cur_height = im.size[1]
    # print(cur_width, cur_height)
​
height_fac = 113 / cur_height
​
new_width = int(cur_width * height_fac)
size = new_width, 113
​
imresize = im.resize((size), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # Resize so height = 113 while keeping aspect ratio
now_width = imresize.size[0]
now_height = imresize.size[1]
    # Generate crops of size 113x113 from this resized image and keep random 10% of crops
​
avail_x_points = list(range(0, now_width - 113 ))# total x start points are from 0 to width -113
​
    # Pick random x%
factor = 0.1 
pick_num = int(len(avail_x_points)*factor)

random_startx = sample(avail_x_points,  pick_num)
​
for start in random_startx:
  imcrop = imresize.crop((start, 0, start+113, 113))
  images.append(np.asarray(imcrop))
T_test = np.array(images)
print (T_test.shape)
T_test = T_test.reshape(T_test.shape[0], 113, 113, 1)
    #convert to float and normalize
T_test = T_test.astype('float32')
T_test /= 255
shuffle(T_test)  
print (T_test.shape)
```

T_test shape was (3, 113, 113, 3) and it was a black and white picture of handwriting.
This is the error :

```
     34 T_test = np.array(images)
     35 print (T_test.shape)
---> 36 T_test = T_test.reshape(T_test.shape[0], 113, 113, 1)
     37     #convert to float and normalize
     38 T_test = T_test.astype('float32')
```

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 114921 into shape
>   (3,113,113,1)
>   I also use

```
predictions = model.predict(T_test, verbose =1)
```

so I can't change it into (T_test.shape[0], 113, 113, 3)

Comment: No , I think it's  T_test = T_test [: , 113 , 113, 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images have 3 channels, so you need to use 3 instead of 1:

```
T_test = T_test.reshape(T_test.shape[0], 113, 113, 3)
```

Comment: I also use : 
` ` `
predictions = model.predict(T_test, verbose =1)

` ` `
so I can't change it into (T_test.shape[0], 113, 113, 3)

Comment: @trungpham what's the problem if you do that?